# how to view network traffic when debugging in visual studio cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS tool for Cordova to run my app via Remote Device on my iphone (build/deploy from mac using vs-mda-remote). I see there's the DOM Explorer and Javascript Console which let's me do most of what I need for debugging.

However, there's one piece missing that I can't find is a way to view network traffic. I see the Javascript console shows

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)  MyApiCallEndpoint(0,0)
```

How can I inspect this request/response in more detail from Visual Studio (or otherwise if it's not possible from VS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently added a new network profiler to VS ([details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studio-s-network-tool.aspx)), but it doesn't currently support Cordova projects running on Android or iOS (I'm noting your implicit request!). In the meantime, we would recommend using Fiddler (which is just a generally awesome tool) and configuring your device to connect to it as a proxy ([details here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforios)). That will let you view all traffic made by your app.

Comment: Thanks! I had some trouble setting up the iphone to fiddler proxy. The online marker in the Fiddler toolbar showed me 4 diff IP addresses. I tried each but all 4 couldn't access http://<fiddleip>:8888 from the iphone. I got past it though by restarting the computer and using a free iphone app called Network Ping Lite which let me ping the entire subnet. I recognized one of the IPs and used that one and it worked. I think the restart was the real magic though, since I tried the working IP before.

Comment: Am looking forward to the network tab working with cordova apps. Here's the uservoice item https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7551796-network-calls-debugger-for-cordova